# Creating a While Loop so Invalid Choices take user back to start of sub menu

Tags: java

I am new to Java and I am having trouble getting a loop to work where an invalid selection ( if the user were to input a number that wasn't a ticket option) would take the user back to start of menu. Can I please have some suggestions or be pointed in the right direction so as I can get this to work.

Thanks.

```
    enter code here

 //Start page banner
  System.out.println("***************************************************");
  System.out.println("      Welcome to ABC Theme Park Ticket Sales");
  System.out.println("***************************************************");

  //Start page options
  System.out.println("[1] Unlimited Ride Tickets");
  System.out.println("[2] Single Ride Tickets");
  System.out.println("***************************************************");
  System.out.println("Please Enter Your Ticket Selection:");

  ticketSelection = sc.nextInt();

  //Unlimited ride bannner
  if (ticketSelection == 1)
  {
        System.out.println("***************************************************");
        System.out.println("              Unlimited Ride Tickets");
        System.out.println("***************************************************");

        System.out.println("***Discounts Available for Purchases of 15 or More Tickets***");

        //Unlimited ride ticket options
        System.out.println("[1] 4 Person Family Pass");
        System.out.println("[2] Adult *13 years and over");
        System.out.println("[3] Child *4 to 12 years");
        System.out.println("[4] 3 years and under");
        System.out.println("Please Enter Your Ticket Selection:");

        unlimitedRide = sc.nextInt();
      switch (unlimitedRide) 
      {
         //Unlimited ride Family Pass
          case 1: 
              System.out.println("Family Pass Price $139.95");
              System.out.println("Please Enter Quantity to be Purchased");
              qtyTicket = sc.nextDouble();
              orderTotal = qtyTicket * 139.95;
              break;
        //Unlimited ride Adult Pass    
          case 2:
              System.out.println("Adult Ticket Price $39.95");
              System.out.println("Please Enter Quantity to be Purchased");
              qtyTicket = sc.nextDouble();
              orderTotal = qtyTicket * 39.95;
              break;
        //Unlimited ride Child Pass      
          case 3:
              System.out.println("Child Ticket Price $29.95");
              System.out.println("Please Enter Quantity to be Purchased");
              qtyTicket = sc.nextDouble();
              orderTotal = qtyTicket * 29.95;
              break;
        //Unlimited ride children under 3    
          case 4:
              System.out.println("Children Under Three are Free of Charge!!!!!!!");
              break;
      }
            // Now Provide total price and calculate discount
            if (qtyTicket <14)
            {
                // no discount applieed
                System.out.println("Total:");
                System.out.println(fmt.format(orderTotal));
            }
            else if ((qtyTicket >= 15) && (qtyTicket <=40))
            {
                // Apply discount 10%
                System.out.println("Total:");
                System.out.println(fmt.format(orderTotal));
                System.out.println("Discount Applied 10%");
                orderTotal *= 0.9;
                System.out.println("Amount Due:");
                System.out.println(fmt.format(orderTotal));
            }

            else if ((qtyTicket >=41) && (qtyTicket <=100)){
                // Apply Discount 15%
                System.out.println("Total:");
                System.out.println(fmt.format(orderTotal));
                System.out.println("Super Discount Applied 15%!!");
                orderTotal *= 0.85;
                System.out.println("Amount Due:");
                System.out.println(fmt.format(orderTotal));

            }
            if (qtyTicket >100);
            //Limited to purchase of 100 tickets
                System.out.println("Customers Limited to Purchase of 100 Tickets Only");
  }

  if (ticketSelection == 2)
  { 
    //Single ride banner    
        System.out.println("***************************************************");
        System.out.println("              Single Ride Tickets                  ");
        System.out.println("***************************************************");

    //Single ride pass options  
        System.out.println("[1] Adult *13 years and over");
        System.out.println("[2] Child *4 to 12 years");
        System.out.println("[3] 3 years and under");
        System.out.println("Please Enter Your Ticket Selection:");

        singleRide = sc.nextInt();
        switch (singleRide) 
        {
    //Single ride Adult pass  
        case 1:
              System.out.println("Adult Ticket Price $9.95");
              System.out.println("Please Enter Quantity to be Purchased");
              qtyTicket = sc.nextDouble();
              orderTotal = qtyTicket * 9.95;
              System.out.println("Total:");
              System.out.println(fmt.format(orderTotal));
              break;
    //Single ride Child pass          
          case 2:
              System.out.println("Child Ticket Price $8.95");
              System.out.println("Please Enter Quantity to be Purchased");
              qtyTicket = sc.nextDouble();
              orderTotal = qtyTicket * 8.95;
              System.out.println("Total:");
              System.out.println(fmt.format(orderTotal));
              break;
    //Single ride Children under 3          
          case 3:
              System.out.println("Children Under Three are Free of Charge!!!!!!!");
              break;


           }
        }
    }     
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with `do...while` loop. Like this:

```
int selectedOption = -1;
do {
    // Show your menu and read de option typed 
} while (selectedOption != 1 && selectedOption != 2 && ...);
```

Them put your code that use `selectedOption` to do something.

I hope help you and sorry for my english.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
boolean done = true;

// loop 1
while (true) {
    // Start page banner
    System.out.println("***************************************************");
    System.out.println("      Welcome to ABC Theme Park Ticket Sales");
    System.out.println("***************************************************");

    //Start page options
    System.out.println("[1] Unlimited Ride Tickets");
    System.out.println("[2] Single Ride Tickets");
    System.out.println("***************************************************");
    System.out.println("Please Enter Your Ticket Selection:");

    ticketSelection = sc.nextInt();

    // Unlimited ride bannner
    if (ticketSelection == 1) {

        // loop 2
        while (true) {
            System.out.println("***************************************************");
            System.out.println("              Unlimited Ride Tickets");
            System.out.println("***************************************************");

            .......

            unlimitedRide = sc.nextInt();

            switch (unlimitedRide) 
            {
                case 1: 
                    ...

                case 2:
                    ....

                case 3:
                    ...

                case 4:
                    ...

                // Add default case to handle any other choice. Set "done" to false so it repeats Loop 2
                default:
                    System.out.println("Incorrect choice.");
                    done = false;
                    break;
            }

            // if success, break from Loop 2. Else repeat Loop 2
            if (done == true) {
                break;
            }
        }

        ....
    }
    else if (ticketSelection == 2) {

        // Loop 3
        while (true) {
            //Single ride banner    
            System.out.println("***************************************************");
            System.out.println("              Single Ride Tickets                  ");
            System.out.println("***************************************************");

            ....

            singleRide = sc.nextInt();

            switch (singleRide) 
            {
                case 1:
                    ....

                case 2:
                    ....

                case 3:
                    ....

                // Add default case to handle any other choice. Set "done" to false so it repeats Loop 3
                default:
                    System.out.println("Incorrect choice.");
                    done = false;
                    break;
            }

            // if success, break from Loop 3. Else repeat Loop 3
            if (done == true) {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    else {
        // set to false so it repeats Loop 1
        System.out.println("Incorrect choice.");
        done = false;
    }

    // if success, break from Loop 1. Else repeat Loop 1
    if (done == true) {
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use do while loops and see if the user types in an option outside of the range of the menu choices. Along with this, you can use some extra methods to organise your menus a little bit and keep all that code separate so it doesn't get in the way.

Use this example I am about to show you to amend your code and also change it to suit your needs.

Here is a working example of your code with some extra methods to clean up menus and also use of the do while.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int unlimitedRide;
    int ticketSelection;
    double qtyTicket = 0.0;
    double orderTotal = 0.0;
    int singleRide = 0;

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    do
    {
        printMainMenu();

        ticketSelection = sc.nextInt();
    }
    while(ticketSelection < 1 || ticketSelection > 2);

    //Unlimited ride bannner
    switch(ticketSelection)
    {
        case 1:
            do
            {
                printUnlimitedRidesMenu();

                unlimitedRide = sc.nextInt();
                switch (unlimitedRide) {
                    //Unlimited ride Family Pass
                    case 1:
                        System.out.println("Family Pass Price $139.95");
                        System.out.println("Please Enter Quantity to be Purchased");
                        qtyTicket = sc.nextDouble();
                        orderTotal = qtyTicket * 139.95;
                        break;
                    //Unlimited ride Adult Pass
                    case 2:
                        System.out.println("Adult Ticket Price $39.95");
                        System.out.println("Please Enter Quantity to be Purchased");
                        qtyTicket = sc.nextDouble();
                        orderTotal = qtyTicket * 39.95;
                        break;
                    //Unlimited ride Child Pass
                    case 3:
                        System.out.println("Child Ticket Price $29.95");
                        System.out.println("Please Enter Quantity to be Purchased");
                        qtyTicket = sc.nextDouble();
                        orderTotal = qtyTicket * 29.95;
                        break;
                    //Unlimited ride children under 3
                    case 4:
                        System.out.println("Children Under Three are Free of Charge!!!!!!!");
                        break;
                }
                // Now Provide total price and calculate discount
                if (qtyTicket < 14) {
                    // no discount applieed
                    System.out.println("Total:");
                    System.out.println(orderTotal);//fmt.format(orderTotal));
                } else if ((qtyTicket >= 15) && (qtyTicket <= 40)) {
                    // Apply discount 10%
                    System.out.println("Total:");
                    System.out.println(orderTotal);//(fmt.format(orderTotal));
                    System.out.println("Discount Applied 10%");
                    orderTotal *= 0.9;
                    System.out.println("Amount Due:");
                    System.out.println(orderTotal);//(fmt.format(orderTotal));
                } else if ((qtyTicket >= 41) && (qtyTicket <= 100)) {
                    // Apply Discount 15%
                    System.out.println("Total:");
                    System.out.println(orderTotal);//(fmt.format(orderTotal));
                    System.out.println("Super Discount Applied 15%!!");
                    orderTotal *= 0.85;
                    System.out.println("Amount Due:");
                    System.out.println(orderTotal);//(fmt.format(orderTotal));

                }
                if (qtyTicket > 100) {
                    //Limited to purchase of 100 tickets
                    System.out.println("Customers Limited to Purchase of 100 Tickets Only");
                }
            }
            while(unlimitedRide < 1 || unlimitedRide > 4);
            break;

        case 2:
            do
            {
                printSingleRidesMenu();

                singleRide = sc.nextInt();
                switch (singleRide) {
                    //Single ride Adult pass
                    case 1:
                        System.out.println("Adult Ticket Price $9.95");
                        System.out.println("Please Enter Quantity to be Purchased");
                        qtyTicket = sc.nextDouble();
                        orderTotal = qtyTicket * 9.95;
                        System.out.println("Total:");
                        System.out.println(orderTotal);//(fmt.format(orderTotal));
                        break;
                    //Single ride Child pass
                    case 2:
                        System.out.println("Child Ticket Price $8.95");
                        System.out.println("Please Enter Quantity to be Purchased");
                        qtyTicket = sc.nextDouble();
                        orderTotal = qtyTicket * 8.95;
                        System.out.println("Total:");
                        System.out.println(orderTotal);//(fmt.format(orderTotal));
                        break;
                    //Single ride Children under 3
                    case 3:
                        System.out.println("Children Under Three are Free of Charge!!!!!!!");
                        break;


                }
            }
            while(singleRide < 1 || singleRide > 3);
            break;

        default:
            System.out.println("...");
            break;
    }
}
```

A new method created for the main menu:

```
public static void printMainMenu()
{
    //Start page banner
    System.out.println("***************************************************");
    System.out.println("      Welcome to ABC Theme Park Ticket Sales");
    System.out.println("***************************************************");

    //Start page options
    System.out.println("[1] Unlimited Ride Tickets");
    System.out.println("[2] Single Ride Tickets");
    System.out.println("***************************************************");
    System.out.println("Please Enter Your Ticket Selection:");
}
```

One for the unlimited rides menu:

```
public static void printUnlimitedRidesMenu()
{
    System.out.println("***************************************************");
    System.out.println("              Unlimited Ride Tickets");
    System.out.println("***************************************************");

    System.out.println("***Discounts Available for Purchases of 15 or More Tickets***");

    //Unlimited ride ticket options
    System.out.println("[1] 4 Person Family Pass");
    System.out.println("[2] Adult *13 years and over");
    System.out.println("[3] Child *4 to 12 years");
    System.out.println("[4] 3 years and under");
    System.out.println("Please Enter Your Ticket Selection:");
}
```

And a final one for the singles menu:

```
public static void printSingleRidesMenu()
{
    //Single ride banner
    System.out.println("***************************************************");
    System.out.println("              Single Ride Tickets                  ");
    System.out.println("***************************************************");

    //Single ride pass options
    System.out.println("[1] Adult *13 years and over");
    System.out.println("[2] Child *4 to 12 years");
    System.out.println("[3] 3 years and under");
    System.out.println("Please Enter Your Ticket Selection:");
}
```

Comment: No worries, if it helped you achieve your question, mark it as answered. Much appreciated :)